# Adjoints of $C \rightarrow \mathbf{1}$ and $\Delta : C \rightarrow C \times C$ and (Co)Products

Tags: category-theory

From pg. 97 of *Categories for the Working Mathematician*, the author starts out with something that I understand:

> To assert that a category $C$ has all finite products and coproducts is to assert that products, terminal, and initial and coproducts exist,

but then asserts something that don't understand:

> thus the functors $C \rightarrow \mathbf{1}$ and $\Delta : C \rightarrow C \times C$ have both left and right adjoints. Indeed, the left adjoints give initial object and coproduct, respectively, while the right adjoints give terminal object and product, respectively.

Why is this?

Comment: Look at the functor $G: C\to \mathbf{1}$ for instance. It having a right adjoint means : there exists $F: \mathbf{1}\to C$, and a natural bijection $Hom(A, Fe)\simeq Hom(GA, e)$ where $A$ is any object in $C$ and $e$ is the unique object in $\mathbf{1}$. But $Hom(GA,e) =\{id_e\}$ by definition of $\mathbf{1}$ so for all $C$-objects $A$, $Hom(A,Fe)$ has size $1$: that's precisely saying that $Fe$ is a terminal object. Similarly, a left adjoint for $G$ provides an initial object.

Comment: Then you can prove, using the definition of adjoints and (co) products that adjoints for $\Delta$ provide (co)-products

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can verify by direct computation; e.g. $L$ is left adjoint to $\Delta$ iff

$$\begin{align} \hom_{C} (L(X,Y), Z) 
&\cong \hom_{C \times C}((X,Y), \Delta Z) 
\\&\cong \hom_{C \times C}((X, Y), (Z, Z))
\\&\cong \hom_{C}(X, Z) \times \hom_{C}(Y, Z)
\end{align}$$

but this is precisely the universal property of the binary coproduct:

$$ \hom_C(X \amalg Y, Z) \cong \hom_{C}(X, Z) \times \hom_{C}(Y, Z) $$

and thus $L$ is left adjoint to $\Delta$ if and only if (binary coproducts exist and) there is a natural isomorphism $L(X,Y) \cong X \amalg Y$.

Comment: So -- just to confirm my understanding -- making $L$ the functor in which $L(X,Y) = X \amalg Y$ would imply that $L$ is left adjoint to $\Delta$; is this the case?

Comment: @user1770201: That is correct.